# Facebook shares -> 0 due to empty anchor (href=""). $facebook_count['page_url'] URL destroyed due to some kind of JS?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

Sorry guys, hard to make this question generic, I hope I achieve that in the end:

The following page: http://www.belowtheriver.co.uk has a share count in the sidebar, which is 0.
When I open the widget panel, save the facebook pageid field blank, then save the facebook pageid in the pageid field, the count comes back. Then, it will spontaneously go to 0 again. (happened about 5 times in the last month)

The demo theme seems to never have the facebook count crash to 0, so it is something in my code.

It isn't an option unfortunately to remove all plugins for a week due to site traffic.

The question: Does anyone have any suggestions as to what might be killing this facebook page count?

Inspecting the element, we see that the anchor tag has no hyperlink:

The php is as follows:

```
if ( $facebook ) {
    $facebook_count = vw_get_facebook_count( $facebook );
    ?>
        <div class="vw-social-counter vw-social-counter-facebook">
            <a class="vw-social-counter-icon" href="<?php echo esc_attr( $facebook_count['page_url'] ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Like our facebook', 'envirra' ) ?>" target="_blank"><i class="icon-social-facebook"></i></a>
            <div class="vw-social-counter-counter">
                <div class="vw-social-counter-count"><?php echo vw_number_prefixes( $facebook_count['fans_count'] ); ?></div>
                <div class="vw-social-counter-unit"><?php _e( 'Fans', 'envirra' ) ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    <?php
}
```

and:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'vw_get_facebook_count' ) ) {
    function vw_get_facebook_count( $page_id ) {
        $facebook = get_transient('vw_facebook_count');
        if ($facebook !== false) return $facebook;

        $facebook['page_id'] = $page_id;

        try {
            $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$page_id;
            $reply = json_decode( vw_get_subscriber_counter( $url ) );
            $facebook['fans_count'] = $reply->likes;
            $facebook['page_url'] = $reply->link;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $saved_facebook = get_option( 'vw_social_counter_facebook', array() );
            if ( ! empty( $saved_facebook['fans_count'] ) && $saved_facebook['page_id'] == $facebook['page_id'] ) {
                // Restore previous counter
                $facebook['fans_count'] = $saved_facebook['fans_count'];
                $facebook['page_url'] = $saved_facebook['page_url'];
            } else {
                $facebook['fans_count'] = '0';
                $facebook['page_url'] = 'http://www.facebook.com';
            }
        }

        update_option( 'vw_social_counter_facebook', $facebook );
        set_transient( 'vw_facebook_count', $facebook, VW_CONST_SOCIAL_COUNTER_CACHE_EXPIRE );
        return $facebook;
    }
}
```

However, I reckon the clue is in the page source...
Any hints as to where to spot what is wiping the page count to 0?

Also, any ideas how to make this post useful to others?

N.B. for the other website, http://www.gasholder.london, I just re-saved the pageID and the page count is back to the correct number. We can see how long from this time until it crashes to 0 again.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly an answer to your question I'm afraid, but I hope it helps...

Debugging in a live environment is never a good idea, especially as a project grows and becomes more complex. I suggest a [staging environment](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-staging-environment-for-a-wordpress-site/) for testing plugins, compatibility, theme changes, and experimenting to hunt bugs.

The sample code could return 0 for a number of reasons, it's hard to answer without diving into the plugin and working with it. The `$facebook` variable is passed through some unseen functions.

I would look for a trigger. Create and edit some test pages/posts in the admin console to hunt down where the bug is triggered. If it happens on a set day/time then check for cron jobs running which might affect the plugin. Just a hunch - if its losing track of page IDs, check for empty form posts in admin pages or the accidental deletion of lookup records.

When you can find the cause you can flesh out your question here, fix it or report the bug to the plugin author.

Comment: Well, whaddya know? Since I posted this question (actually in the last 30hours), gasholder.london's facebook count crashed again :)
Now to try and spot the trigger (which seems to happen when the website is not being administrated.

Can you kindly expand on your hunch?
 - empty form posts: Do you mean posts that have no content in the body?
 - deletion of lookup records: I'm not sure what that is.

Thanks for your advice so far, it's actually really useful/constructive :)